# function of crypt called "ICE"

Tags: encryption, reference-request, known-plaintext-attack, chosen-plaintext-attack

Using `exeinfo`, I have identified a function of `crypt` called `ICE`.

**What is it? How can I find out the workings of the function?**

Some idea's I had for doing this were:

- Perhaps there is a reference
- Could one reverse engineer it?
- If I have examples of (plaintext-ciphertext) pairs, could I construct an equivalent function without knowing the key?

Comment: Have you, eehm, tried to google for ICE?

Comment: Yes. I have a look and says that is equal to DES, in is structure.

Comment: Then what is your question? The source code is freely available.

Comment: @user36384: I have edited the question to reflect what I think you're asking. If not, please could you edit it further to reflect what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

[ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICE_%28cipher%29) is a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) operating on 64-bit data blocks (which is a bit dated, and less than perfectly safe in some usage scenario involving a huge amount of data). Depending on implementations, the key can be 64-bit (which is quite dated, and unsafe against a potent attacker), or some higher multiple (128-bit is fine for longer than I dare try making predictions).

The ICE home page is [here](http://www.darkside.com.au/ice/index.html). There is source, so no need for reverse-engineering.

I am not aware of any near-practical attack on the full cipher, or of any devastating attack even on the reduced version Thin-ICE (which uses 8 rounds instead of 16). And (as a consequence) I know no efficient method to recover the key or otherwise build an equivalent function from plaintext-ciphertext pairs alone, without any form of access to the key.

Best technique I know to recover the keys from plaintext-ciphertext pairs alone is brute force (trying all keys until finding one that fits 2 example pairs), which is conceivable for the 64-bit key version (only). But we are talking of thousands of CPU.years, or massive investment in ASICs or FPGAs.